# table not creating in database in asp.net core mvc net6

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

i deleted subject table from database. After that i deleted subjectController ,recreate subject model and generated subjectController with EF .Then i do migration but subject table is not creating in database.

Comment: Did you run update database command?

Comment: @Rena:  yes i did. But it  didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Kewang Limbu, Pls check the DbContext if contains the `DbSet<Subject>`. Then check your newest migration file if it create the Subject table.